# Does prediction-at-the-means give the correct survival function in the long run?

Tags: survival, hazard

If you fit a Cox model, it's possible to come up with an estimate of the baseline hazard function using the Breslow step estimator. In R, this is the `basehaz` function, but by default it centers the covariates. Importantly, that is not the baseline hazard function, i.e. the hazard function when all covariates are 0. With centered continuous covariates, the cumulative hazard function approximates the *unadjusted* hazard functinon.

However, if you adjust for categorical covariates, centering the dummy-encoded values gives prediction-at-the-means and makes no sense because the observed data have either dummy variables equal to 0 or 1, but not some fractional value.

To get a consistent estimate of the survival function, it seems to me that you would have to actually get the baseline hazard function, then predict survival for each covariate level, and average them together point-wise for the population level survival.

Would this be correct?

I tried to explore this with a simulation but I can't seem to create the disparate findings I would expect.

```
library(survival)
set.seed(123)
n <- 1000
x <- rep.int(0:2, times=c(n/10, n/10, 8*n/10))
y <- rweibull(n, exp(0.3*(x==1) + 0.7*(x==2)), 1/3)
fit <- coxph(Surv(y) ~ factor(x))
bh <- basehaz(fit)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(bh$time, exp(-bh$hazard), type='l', main='Baseline hazard')
plot(survfit(Surv(y) ~ 1), add=T, col='red', main='Empirical survival')
```

[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused: if it estimates the "adjusted baseline" (i.e., survival function with mean covariate value rather than 0), this should be mathematically equivalent to estimating the true baseline, but probably more numerically stable. Then, if we want to find the "true" baseline, we simply readjust the adjusted baseline by the linear predictors.

Comment: @CliffAB prediction-at-the-means means that, if you adjust for a binary covariate that has a prevalence of 33%, and the intercept is -3 and the coefficient is 1, then the predicted response is -3 + 1 * 0.33, i.e. the prevalence is imputed as a novel response level.

Comment: That I understand. But when computing the Brenslow estimator, it's mathematically equivalent to whether you recenter all values to be baseline (i.e. covariates = 0), or at the means. Since baseline is more likely to be an extreme (suppose you have a covariate for height, for example), fitting at the mean leads to solving the equivalent maximum likelihood problem, but (most likely) in a more numerically stable manner.

Comment: @CliffAB Interesting. If you could show/cite that (either as an answer or comment), I'd be interested. I know it's not the case for logistic regression since the risk of the average is not the average of the risk.

Comment: Without having gone into it too deeply, my understanding is that the Brenslow estimator can be shown as a maximum likelihood estimator, rather than a methods of moment estimator. Paper where I saw Breslow presented as an MLE: "On the Breslow Estimator", by D.Y. Lin (2007). I will note that they just state "we can see that the Breslow estimator maximumizes the likelihood function" (or something like that) rather than rigorously demonstrating that.